# How to increase y-axis in barplot?

Tags: r, plot

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/R
layout(matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5), ncol=1))

# main plots
par(mar=c(5,2,4,2))

fcm <-c(14.0,14.1,13.0,14.2,14.7,13.8,14.0)
gk  <-c(12.1,12.5,12.2,12.0,11.5,12.0,11.4)
gg  <-c(14.0,14.1,13.3,12.8,12.0,12.2,12.0)
data1 <- rbind(fcm,gk,gg)
colnames(data1) <- c(6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

fcm <-c(2.65,2.55,2.4,2.45,2.45,2.5,2.45)
gk  <-c(2.45,2.55,2.4,2.3,2.2,2.35,2.1)
gg  <-c(2.6,2.65,2.5,2.35,2.4,2.4,2.2)
data2 <- rbind(fcm,gk,gg)
colnames(data2) <- c(6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

fcm <-c(8.8,6.5,6.6,8.2,8.0,8.4,9.0)
gk  <-c(12.7,11.0,11.1,10.5,10.7,10.0,9.5)
gg  <-c(2.1,2.1,1.8,2.0,2.0,1.9,1.8)
data3 <- rbind(fcm,gk,gg)
colnames(data3) <- c(6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

fcm <-c(0.47,0.53,0.45,0.39,0.40,0.47,0.48)
gk  <-c(0.45,0.51,0.34,0.40,0.42,0.42,0.44)
data4 <- rbind(fcm,gk)
colnames(data4) <- c(6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

barplot(as.matrix(data1),ylim=c(0,15),main="P wave",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="traveltime rms(ms)",
        col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE)
barplot(as.matrix(data2),ylim=c(0,3),main="MT",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="MT functions",
        col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE)
barplot(as.matrix(data3),ylim=c(0,13),main="XBI",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="index value",
        col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE)
barplot(as.matrix(data4),ylim=c(0,0.6),main="NCE",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="index value",
        col=c("red", "black"), beside=TRUE)

par(mai=c(0,0,0,0))
plot.new()
legend(legend = c("fcm","gk","gg"), fill = c( "red", "black", "green"), 
    "center", horiz=TRUE)
```

This image will be part of my paper,plan to submit it to a journal.I am afraid editor will complain that values are not visible.How to change this?My goal is that there is clear distinction between all barplots,of course if this is possible.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stacking your plots is compressing them unnecessarily & creating a lot of wasted white space.

Why not shift to a 2x2 representation?

Basically all you need to change is:

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5), ncol=2))
```

I get this output with `par(mar=c(3.1,2.1,2.1,0.1))`:

[image]

You may notice we're giving too much space to the legend; this can be fixed by tinkering with the `heights` parameter to `layout`; here's the output with `heights=c(.45,.45,.1)`. See `?layout`.

[image]

Comment: @Works fine,just number of clusters has disappeared.

Comment: @RichardRublev yea I noticed that. I imagine it's due to my particular choice of margins... play round with `oma` and `mar` until they come back :)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer @MichaelChirico's answer, but if you need them to be stacked in one column for some reason, here is another option. I've added comments to explain the changes to your original code. Basically, I've created some additional vertical space by playing with the margins and the layout matrix, and getting rid of unnecessary x-axis titles:

```
# Change layout matrix to allow more vertical space for bottom plot
# (since it is now the only one with an x-axis title)
layout(matrix(1:5, ncol=1), heights=c(rep(0.21,3), 0.26, 0.11))  

# main plots
par(mar=c(2,2.5,3.5,2))   # Decrease top and bottom margins

fcm <-c(14.0,14.1,13.0,14.2,14.7,13.8,14.0)
gk  <-c(12.1,12.5,12.2,12.0,11.5,12.0,11.4)
gg  <-c(14.0,14.1,13.3,12.8,12.0,12.2,12.0)
data1 <- rbind(fcm,gk,gg)

colnames(data1) <- c(6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

fcm <-c(2.65,2.55,2.4,2.45,2.45,2.5,2.45)
gk  <-c(2.45,2.55,2.4,2.3,2.2,2.35,2.1)
gg  <-c(2.6,2.65,2.5,2.35,2.4,2.4,2.2)
data2 <- rbind(fcm,gk,gg)
colnames(data2) <- c(6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

fcm <-c(8.8,6.5,6.6,8.2,8.0,8.4,9.0)
gk  <-c(12.7,11.0,11.1,10.5,10.7,10.0,9.5)
gg  <-c(2.1,2.1,1.8,2.0,2.0,1.9,1.8)
data3 <- rbind(fcm,gk,gg)
colnames(data3) <- c(6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

fcm <-c(0.47,0.53,0.45,0.39,0.40,0.47,0.48)
gk  <-c(0.45,0.51,0.34,0.40,0.42,0.42,0.44)
data4 <- rbind(fcm,gk)
colnames(data4) <- c(6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

# Remove x-axis title from first three plots
# Add las=1 to all plots, so y-axis labels will be rotated
barplot(as.matrix(data1),ylim=c(0,15),main="P wave",
        ylab="traveltime rms(ms)", las=1,
        col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE)
barplot(as.matrix(data2),ylim=c(0,3),main="MT",
        ylab="MT functions", las=1,
        col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE)
barplot(as.matrix(data3),ylim=c(0,13),main="XBI",
        ylab="index value", las=1,
        col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE)

# Change bottom margin for last plot so x-axis title will be included
par(mar=c(4,2.5,3.5,2))
barplot(as.matrix(data4),ylim=c(0,0.6),main="NCE",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="index value", las=1,
        col=c("red", "black"), beside=TRUE)

par(mai=c(0,0,0,0))
plot.new()
legend(legend = c("fcm","gk","gg"), fill = c( "red", "black", "green"), 
       "center", horiz=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't post comment, so I've decided to add it as answer...

Let's try with las and cex parameters:

```
barplot(as.matrix(data1),ylim=c(0,15),main="P wave",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="traveltime rms(ms)",
        col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE, las=1, cex.axis=.9)
```

You can also enlarge bars area by reducing first and third element of mar paratemer.